# Split a dictionary where values of keys are multiple lists into train and test set Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, split

Say I have a dictionary with two keys, spam and ham, for spam and ham text or email messages that looks like the following:

```py
data = {
    'spam': [
        ['hi', "what's", 'going', 'on', 'sexy', 'thing'], 
        ['1-800', 'call', 'girls', 'if', "you're", 'lonely'], 
        ['sexy', 'girls', 'for', 'youuuuuu']], 
    'ham': [['hey', 'hey', 'I', 'got', 'your', 'message,', "I'll", 'be', 'home', 'soon!!!'], 
        ['Madden', 'MUT', 'time', 'boys']]}
```

I want to split the dictionary into training and test sets (starting with 80/20 training to test).  I want the split to be regardless of key, so just subset 80% of the total messages for my training set and 20% of the total messages for my test set.  In this small example we have 5 total messages (3 in spam and 2 in ham).  I've looked around for solutions, but haven't found anything yet that handles this type of situation.

Comment: I should mention, the lists have to be lists of words, not strings, because I am implementing a Naive Bayes Classifier and need to get probabilities of word occurrences in difference classes (i.e. spam and ham).  I guess if a solution involved the lists being strings I could just split the strings into words after creating my test and training sets.

Comment: Have you considered just using something like Pandas? I think dictionaries are a bit limited for this kind of task, no?

Comment: Do you need to keep a reference to the key, then?

Comment: @AMC yeah it is probably better for this situation, except that I did all my word probabilities given a class and all other calculations for this project using my data in dictionary form.  The assignment is due Tuesday, so I don't think I'd have the time or knowledge to switch up at this point.

Comment: Yes a reference to the key, ideally it would be just two new dictionaries in the same format as the full data set.  But, @abc's answer below converting the dictionary to a list to make the train and test would be ok.  I could just convert the training and test lists back to a dictionary so they work with the rest of my program.

Comment: _yeah it is probably better for this situation, except that I did all my word probabilities given a class and all other calculations for this project using my data in dictionary form. The assignment is due Tuesday, so I don't think I'd have the time or knowledge to switch up at this point._ Aaah, yeah, you might not want to take that risk. I did include a solution with Pandas, if you want to take a look. If you do have time, you should definitely modify at least a few parts of your program.

Comment: nice dataset! Amazon also has a girl supply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the aptly named [`sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html):

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

data = {
    'spam': [
        ['hi', "what's", 'going', 'on', 'sexy', 'thing'],
        ['1-800', 'call', 'girls', 'if', "you're", 'lonely'],
        ['sexy', 'girls', 'for', 'youuuuuu']],
    'ham': [['hey', 'hey', 'I', 'got', 'your', 'message,', "I'll", 'be', 'home', 'soon!!!'],
            ['Madden', 'MUT', 'time', 'boys']]}

all_messages = [(words, k) for k, v in data.items() for words in v]

train, test = train_test_split(list(all_messages), test_size=0.2)
```

---

You can, and probably should, use something more powerful, like Pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

data_dict = {
    'spam': [
        ['hi', "what's", 'going', 'on', 'sexy', 'thing'],
        ['1-800', 'call', 'girls', 'if', "you're", 'lonely'],
        ['sexy', 'girls', 'for', 'youuuuuu']],
    'ham': [['hey', 'hey', 'I', 'got', 'your', 'message,', "I'll", 'be', 'home', 'soon!!!'],
            ['Madden', 'MUT', 'time', 'boys']]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=((k, words) for k, v in data_dict.items() for words in v))

print(df)

train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2)

print(train)
print(test)
```

Output:

```
      0                                                  1
0  spam               [hi, what's, going, on, sexy, thing]
1  spam           [1-800, call, girls, if, you're, lonely]
2  spam                       [sexy, girls, for, youuuuuu]
3   ham  [hey, hey, I, got, your, message,, I'll, be, h...
4   ham                          [Madden, MUT, time, boys]

      0                                                  1
1  spam           [1-800, call, girls, if, you're, lonely]
2  spam                       [sexy, girls, for, youuuuuu]
0  spam               [hi, what's, going, on, sexy, thing]
3   ham  [hey, hey, I, got, your, message,, I'll, be, h...

     0                          1
4  ham  [Madden, MUT, time, boys]
```

Comment: thanks for the Pandas suggestion.  I will probably update to using that.  Appreciate it.

Comment: What about a stratified split (without using pandas) ? I just can't add that dependency to the current repository

Comment: @PabloRuizRuiz I'm not sure I understand, what do you mean?

Comment: (SOLVED) In case you wanted to to an "stratified" split where the label distribution is kept in both splits (specially useful in imbalanced datasets). I solved it with:
```train, test = train_test_split(list(all_messages), test_size=0.2,
                                   stratify=[message[stratify] for example in dataset]
                                   if stratify
                                   else None
)  
where stratify is the name of the labels "column" or "key" if you are using dicts instead of pandas dataframe

Answer (score 3):

You can convert the dict to a list of tuples and then make the split.

```
>>> l = [(sentence, k) for k,v in data.items() for sentence in v]
>>> random.shuffle(l)
>>> train_size = int(len(l)*0.8)
>>> train, test = l[:train_size], l[train_size:]
>>> len(train)
4
>>> len(test)
1
```

Each element is a pair `(sentence, label)`

```
>>> test[0]
(['Madden', 'MUT', 'time', 'boys'], 'ham')
```

Comment: This is without replacement, correct?  Each sentence or list from the original dictionary can only be chosen once??  If so, that's what I need.

Comment: Given a list of 5 sentences, this divides the list in 2: a train and test one, where each is a pair (sentence, key).